# Obj-C - Recalling user session doesnt recall all data?

Tags: ios, objective-c

After my user logs into my app for the first time, I save their session information in order to recall it later so that they don't need to keep logging in multiple times. That said, in certain parts of my app, I'm pulling data from the session:

**ViewController.m**

```
 NSString *amVerified = [session user][@"user"][@"field_checked_messages"][@"und"][0][@"safe_value"];
```

Oddly enough, the **first time** a session is opened, the following data is returned:

```
 2019-02-08 13:05:59.651056-0800[4681:1246584] SHOW ME EVERYTHING {
        sessid = "sesshere";
        "session_name" = nameofsession;
        token = "tokenhere";
        user =     {
            access = 1549659837;
            created = 1459875505;
            data =         {
                "ckeditor_auto_lang" = t;
                "ckeditor_default" = t;
                "ckeditor_lang" = en;
                "ckeditor_show_toggle" = t;
                "ckeditor_width" = "100%";
                "remember_me" = 0;
            };
            "field_address" =         {
                und =             (
                                    {
                        format = "<null>";
                        "safe_value" = "ADDRESS, Vancouver";
                        value = "ADDRESS, Vancouver";
                    }
                );
            };
            "field_ambassador" =         (
            );
            "field_checked_messages" =         {
                und =             (
                                    {
                        format = "<null>";
                        "safe_value" = "0 10) 9) 10) 10)";
                        value = "0 10) 9) 10) 10)";
                    }
                );
            };
```

And the NSString stated above populates as it should.

***However*** if my user closes the app for a period of time, and comes back to the application later and the session is reopened, the session data only returns half of what it should - e.g. it doesnt return any of the fields associated with 'user':

```
 2019-02-08 13:05:59.651056-0800[4681:1246584] SHOW ME EVERYTHING {
        sessid = "sesshere";
        "session_name" = nameofsession;
        token = "tokenhere";
        user =     {
            access = 1549659837;
            created = 1459875505;
            data =         {
                "ckeditor_auto_lang" = t;
                "ckeditor_default" = t;
                "ckeditor_lang" = en;
                "ckeditor_show_toggle" = t;
                "ckeditor_width" = "100%";
                "remember_me" = 0;
            };
```

And the NSString amVerified (naturally) is NULL. Does anyone have any insight as to why 'user' fields aren't returned when the app is reopened? Here is the code I'm using to re-log a user into the app:

```
 [DIOSUser userMakeSureUserIsLoggedInWithUsername:[keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount]
                                                 andPassword:[keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecValueData]
                                                     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, id response) {


[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:response] forKey:@"diosSession"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


                                                        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
                                                         UITabBarController *yourViewController = (UITabBarController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBar"];
                                                         [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];



UITabBarController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBar"]; 
 [viewController setSelectedIndex:0];


                                                    }
                                                     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, NSError *err) {
                                                         // failure(err);


                                                     }
             ];

        }
```

Comment: you probably overwrite it somewhere. Place a breakpoint to `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: ...]` and see when it's called. Also, saving any session related information (e.g. tokens) to `NSUserDefault` is dangerous and *should never be done*. Use keychain.

Comment: Ahh good to know @Sulthan - will switch to Keychain. Thank you!